# Photo taken through camera intent is losing on quality

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-camera, photo

*The similar SO question-answers is crashing my app.*

I am taking a photo through my camera intent and sending it to my php server over net which is then saving it to a directory. It **is** working fine. But the photo being saved is of compromised quality (~20KB).

I know my mistake. **I read Android documentation to realize I am actually sending the photo thumbnail instead of the photo itself**.  Here is my code

Open Camera Intent to take a photo.

```
addImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Receiving the Image.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        addImage.setImageDrawable(null);
        addImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        addImage.setImageBitmap(photo);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] photoByte = baos.toByteArray();
        encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(photoByte,Base64.DEFAULT);

    }
}
```

**What do I want?**
I simply want to convert my original image (and not the thumbnail) to Base64 encoded string (Just like what I did with the thumbnail).

Any help will be appreciated.

*[ Feel free to suggest edits. :) ]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I simply want to convert my original image (and not the thumbnail)

You do not have an "original image", because you did not include `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`. Add that, and then you have your full-size image (except with buggy camera apps):

```
/***
 Copyright (c) 2008-2016 CommonsWare, LLC
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
 of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
 by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
 OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
 language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

 From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
 https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.camcon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import java.io.File;

public class CameraContentDemoActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String EXTRA_FILENAME=
    "com.commonsware.android.camcon.EXTRA_FILENAME";
  private static final String FILENAME="CameraContentDemo.jpeg";
  private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST=1337;
  private File output=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
      File dir=
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

      dir.mkdirs();
      output=new File(dir, FILENAME);
    }
    else {
      output=(File)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME);
    }

    if (output.exists()) {
      output.delete();
    }

    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));

    startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME, output);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                  Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // spawn an IntentService to encode and upload your File
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Almost got it. But any idea about this error? `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1337, result=-1, data=null} to activity {example.srujan.com.sendimagedemo/example.srujan.com.sendimagedemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @SrujanBarai: You have a bug somewhere in your `onActivityResult()`, with a `NullPointerException`. The stack trace should show you your line of code that is crashing.

Comment: I am accepting the file as Bitmap image, which I shouldn't. Its on the line `photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` I know the problem. I do not know the solution .

Comment: @SrujanBarai: Delete that line, as usually it will not work, and even if it does, it will be the thumbnail. You know where the image is supposed to be. It is in the location that you specified in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Upload the contents of that file. Do that in an `IntentService`, as it may take some time.